# Half of my training missions are missing

Tags: kerbal-space-program

After not playing for a while I re-launched KSP and went back to refresh my skills with the training missions - however I only have the more advanced missions available - how do I reset or re-acquire the missing ones?

For example, I can only see:

- Science
- To the Mun Part 1
- To the Mun Part 2
- Docking
- Asteroid Redirect Mission, Part 1
- Asteroid Redirect Mission, Part 1

I'm missing the intro Flight and Orbit options for example?

I'm running this from Steam and have tried verifying the game cache, but that reported everything was ok.

Looking in the `saves\training` folder I can see the `.sfs` files for the missing tutorials, along with some similarly named directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [turns out](http://steamcommunity.com/app/220200/discussions/0/864974467281442038/#c864974467297924442) there are some issues with tutorial saves across versions - deleting the folders in my `saves\training` folder for the tutorials caused them to show up in game again - I didn't even need to restart KSP for them to re-appear.